# How to handle following dependency conflict in Cabal?

Tags: haskell

When I try to add `scotty` package to my multi-project cabal file, I get following dependency conflict. I am not exactly sure what it means.

```
harshal@Harshals-Linux hello-haskell % cabal build

Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: playground-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: scotty-0.12.1 (dependency of playground)
[__2] trying: warp-3.3.23 (dependency of scotty)
[__3] trying: unix-compat-0.6 (dependency of warp)
[__4] trying: unix-2.7.3/installed-2.7.3 (dependency of warp)
[__5] next goal: directory (dependency of playground)
[__5] rejecting: directory-1.3.7.1/installed-1.3.7.1 (conflict: playground =>
directory>=1.3.8.0)
[__5] rejecting: directory-1.3.8.0 (conflict: unix==2.7.3/installed-2.7.3,
directory => unix>=2.8.0 && <2.9)
[__5] rejecting: directory-1.3.7.1 (conflict: playground =>
directory>=1.3.8.0)
[__5] skipping: directory-1.3.7.0, directory-1.3.6.2, directory-1.3.6.1,
directory-1.3.6.0, directory-1.3.5.0, directory-1.3.4.0, directory-1.3.3.2,
directory-1.3.3.1, directory-1.3.3.0, directory-1.3.2.2, directory-1.3.2.1,
directory-1.3.2.0, directory-1.3.1.5, directory-1.3.1.4, directory-1.3.1.3,
directory-1.3.1.2, directory-1.3.1.1, directory-1.3.1.0, directory-1.3.0.2,
directory-1.3.0.1, directory-1.3.0.0, directory-1.2.7.1, directory-1.2.7.0,
directory-1.2.6.3, directory-1.2.6.2, directory-1.2.5.1, directory-1.2.5.0,
directory-1.2.4.0, directory-1.2.3.1, directory-1.2.3.0, directory-1.2.2.1,
directory-1.2.2.0, directory-1.2.1.0, directory-1.2.0.1, directory-1.2.0.0,
directory-1.1.0.2, directory-1.1.0.1, directory-1.1.0.0, directory-1.0.1.2,
directory-1.0.1.1, directory-1.0.1.0, directory-1.0.0.3, directory-1.0.0.0,
directory-1.2.6.1 (has the same characteristics that caused the previous
version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=1.3.8.0' from 'playground')
[__5] fail (backjumping, conflict set: directory, playground, unix)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: directory, unix, playground,
unix-compat, warp, unix-compat:portable, scotty
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

How can I resolve this dependency conflict?

Comment: I think `scotty` depends on directory-1.3.7.1 but you have an user constraint `directory-1.3.8`. Maybe you can solve with `cabal build --allow-newer`

Comment: Yes, `--allow-newer` is generally the first thing to try. Often a conflict isn't really a conflict at all, but just some package maintainers haven't relaxed their upper boundaries in a while.

Comment: I tried using `--allow-newer` and the resolver ends up resolving the dependencies but the compilation fails. I guess it picks also some other latest package that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this says:

- `playground-0.1.0.0` depends on `directory >= 1.3.8.0`
- `directory-1.3.8.0` is the only apparent solution to `directory >= 1.3.8.0`
- `directory-1.3.8.0` depends on `unix >= 2.8.0 && <2.9`
- we already committed to `unix==2.7.3`, which does not satisfy that constraint

One thing you could try, therefore, is to give it a hint that you want to pick a newer `unix`, by adding a top-level constraint:

```
% cabal build --constraint `unix >=2.8.0 && <2.9`
```

Top-level constraints are "available" earlier than constraints found via searching for dependencies, and so can constrain earlier choices better. (I believe this property -- that constraints get solved and committed to in some not-totally-user-visible order -- is to make the dependency resolution algorithm more efficient. Bummer.)

Comment: The cabal says `--build-depends` is unrecognized 'build' option. But I get the gist of the problem. I am not in a better position to read the dependency conflict stack trace.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Apologies, for `cabal build` the flag is named `--constraint`. I'll update the answer shortly to correct this.

Comment: @HarshalPatil As for reading dependency conflict traces... there's not much to it beyond brute force. Just go slow, and don't be afraid to look back at something you already read.

Comment: I meant "now" and not "not" in my earlier comment :( . But yeah. I indeed get an idea on how to follow the dependency conflict errors. Additionally, this article further helped: https://well-typed.com/blog/2015/03/qualified-goals/